# Regex in google analytics to find specific tags and folder

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-search-console

This is a two part question

1) I have a domain with many sub directories of which some are public and some are private. I want to restrict data coming from private directories in google analytics. I want to exclude all data coming from `domain.com/private/manager`

For eg.

```
domain.com/product/welcomeback.aspx?xnav=welcome&rd=1
domain.com/private/manager/welcomeback.aspx?xnav=welcome&rd=1
domain.com/private/manager/cart.aspx?cart_id=20120
```

Only the first url should be included. I tried setting up a custom filter in google analytics by using the regex on the Request URI field as `.*\/private\/manager\/.*` but it dosent work.

2) I have many parameters in a single url and want to exclude URL that does not have a certain parameter

```
http://www.domain.com/vp/welcomeback.aspx?other=welcome&rd=1
http://www.domain.com/category/product1.aspx?txi=15626&xnid=TopNav_product&xnav=TopNav
http://www.domain.com/product2.aspx?txi=17104&xnid=TopNav_product+(linked+item)_product&subjectid=TopNav
http://www.domain.com/product3.aspx?pg=17104&page=TopNav_product+(linked+item)_product&xnav=TopNav
```

I want to include only parameters pg,page, SubjectId and TopicID.
So by that logic only 2,3 and 4 url will be included and not the first one.
I have `.*\(\&|\?.*((topicid|pg|subjectid|page)).*` but it dosent work.

Can any one help me out with the regex with this?

Comment: I think there must be exclusion filters. There, you can use simpler `(^|/)private/manager(/|$)` to  exclude the first type of URL.

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew that worked! Can you please explain the regex and post it as a answer?

Comment: Sure, I posted with explanations. Note you need no `.*` since the regex in GA checks for partial matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up an exclusion filter, use a simpler regex (there is no need to match the whole string with the regex pattern as, e.g. in Java `matches()` since GA regex checks for *partial* matches):

Use

```
(^|/)private/manager(/|$)
```

This matches:

- `(^|/)` - either start of string or `/`
- `private/manager` - a literal string `(^|/)private/manager(/|$)`
- `(/|$)` - the `/` symbol or end of string.

Comment: Thanks! When I try to include this in the custom regex in the behavior->all site pages report it works but when I add this filter to the entire view and verify it it says it doesn't change the data. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you edit the *All Website Data* view? Check https://blog.kissmetrics.com/google-analytics-data-errors/ saying *Don’t edit this view. Create a new View by going to; Account >> Property >> View >> Create New View. Once you set up your new View, you can add Filters.*

Comment: It is in a test view that I created and not on the the main property

Comment: Anyways I can figure it out. Thanks for your help!
If someone can answer the second part of it it would be great!